# How do I edit current shell command in VI

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, vi

On Linux machines the current bash shell command can be edited in VI (or whatever the EDITOR is set to) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>.

This doesn't seem to work on OS X 10.8. Any ideas on how to edit the current bash command in the default editor?

Comment: This *should* work in 10.8 (at least it does for me). Did you try to unset FCEDIT and EDITOR?

Comment: The documentation for C-xC-e is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-operate_002dand_002dget_002dnext-_0028C_002do_0029) -- what's in your `VISUAL` variable?

Comment: it is not about 10.8. I am on 10.8 and it works fine with me. I did not change anything in my .bash_profile to enable this.

Comment: Note: This Apple.SE question is basically the same as the Super User question ["I'm using Bash in 'vi mode'. What's the hotkey sequence to edit the current command line using an external editor?"](http://superuser.com/questions/736368/im-using-bash-in-vi-mode-whats-the-hotkey-sequence-to-edit-the-current-comm)

Comment: I just realized that I was doing Ctrl+(x,e)  (holding ctrl, pressing x, pressing e, releasing control) -  this is why it didn't work for me. When I changed to pressing  two clear strokes Ctrl-x, release Ctrl, Ctrl-e - then everything started to work perfectly!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You want `set -o vi` (add it to your `~/.bashrc`). Then, to edit the current line, just hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter command mode.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-vi-Mode

To edit the current command in a full-screen editor, set your `VISUAL` environment variable to `vim` (I assume you want `vim`), then in command mode in the current comment, hit <kbd>v</kbd>.

---

To show the mode in the prompt:

```bsh
$ cat ~/.inputrc
set editing-mode vi
set show-mode-in-prompt on
set vi-ins-mode-string +
set vi-cmd-mode-string :
```

Comment: pressing the "v" was the secret sauce I was missing.  thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to get this `v` command while in emacs (non-vi) mode?

Comment: Just do Ctrl-X then Ctrl-E.

Comment: There is no visual indication that I have entered vim editing mode. Is there some setting to turn this on ?

Comment: Yes. See my edit.

Answer (score 10):

Your `edit-and-execute-command` may not be bound for `vi` mode. Try:

`bind -m vi-insert '"\C-x\C-e": edit-and-execute-command'`

To make it permanent, add that line to your `~/.inputrc` file.

(via [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/736461/37933); credit to @unforgettableid for the link)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

If you’re using zsh (as you should), you could add the following to your .zshrc (or .zprofile):

```
export EDITOR=nvim
# Enable Ctrl-x-e to edit command line
autoload -U edit-command-line
# Emacs style
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey '^xe' edit-command-line
bindkey '^x^e' edit-command-line
# Vi style:
# zle -N edit-command-line
# bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
```

Then, reload your .zshrc.

Now all you need to do is hit `Ctrl-x Ctrl-e` (`Ctrl-x e` also works) or, if you use vi style, `ESC v`, and zsh will launch `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR`, allowing you to edit the current command to your hearts content, and once you save & close your editor’s window, ZSH will execute your command.

https://nuclearsquid.com/writings/edit-long-commands/